# Can we know the future with quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism, quantum-eraser

I have created a test scenario.

Please see the image below. Two men working on this test, Erdal and Kervan.

Erdal is in the world, but kervan is 10 light seconds far from the world.

The light source throws a photon once per 10 seconds, And kervan randomly places or removes the mirror 5 seconds after the light source throws the photon.

As I understand from the Delayed-choice quantum eraser if we measure the way of the photon DX will detect the photon as particle form. But if we don't measure the way of the photon DX will detect the photon as a waveform.

So, If this test scenario works, can Erdal know Kervan's decision before he does?

[image]

Comment: We can know the future of the solar system with Newtonian mechanics thousands of years into the future, so I don't understand your question. With regards to QM... the world is relativistic. What comes before what is observer dependent if your observers are moving relative to each other. The classical analysis in the rest system of the experiment does not give you the correct physical answers. And no, photons are not "waveforms". They are irreversible energy exchanges and the analysis is post-hoc in this experiment, observers have to collect all the information at the speed of light, first.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the quantum eraser. I also misunderstood it for a long time because it is often explained in a way that sounds cool, but is misleading (e.g. PBS Space Time on YouTube). What is not emphasized is that at detector D X, it doesn't matter what Kervan does, D X sees no interference on his screen. That is because as soon as the crystal at BBO splits the photon into two entangled photons, there cannot be any interference anymore.

Where the interference "appears" is that if, after the whole experiment is done, Kervan tells Erdal which photons hit detector 1 vs which ones hit detector 2, then if Erdal looks only at the subset of his sample which went into Kervan's detector 1, he will see an interference pattern. And by sampling only the photons from Kervan's detector 2 you also see an interference pattern, offset by one half wavelength. Summing those two patterns together creates the no-interference pattern seen by Erdal, which he sees regardless of whatever Kervan decides to do with his photons. So you only see interference after the fact, by choosing which photons to look at.

A good source to understand the quantum eraser is Sean Carroll's blog ([here](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2019/09/21/the-notorious-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser/?fbclid=IwAR24WQ3gTpqQNPELi1TOTlkIADuarKPDN6FFyr285qMpX1YXbzhvilr749c)).

Comment: Photons don't interfere at all. Interference is the absence of interaction. That's a widely misunderstood physical phenomenon.

Comment: To be fair, PBS SpaceTime has three videos on the subject and explains these issues very well. Yet I doubt people watch all of them.

Comment: @Mauricio I like PBS SpaceTime overall, but from their main video on the topic they say that it is the presence of detectors A and B which prevent interference from occurring, even though the photon only hits those detectors in the future(wow backwards causality!). "A photon hits detector A or B and somehow retroactively influences the previous landing position on the screen!" But this is not the case, it is simply the interaction with the crystal that releases entangled photons that prevents interference from occurring, much earlier on in the course of the experiment.

Comment: @FlatterMann Not sure what you mean that photons don't interfere. They can interfere with themselves; it is not the presence of two photons which causes interference.

Comment: @doublefelix Again you will have to look at the three videos to get exactly what you explained in your answer. You can check for yourself, starting from minute 4 in the last video of the series [Quantum Eraser Answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuvwcsfXIIo&t=294s&ab_channel=PBSSpaceTime) It is sloppy to have put it in three videos but at least they took their time to explain all the important details compared to other channels.

Comment: I mean that interference is the absence of interaction. In linear wave media neither classical wave packets nor quanta interact. We usually demonstrate that with a wave machine or a water trough experiment by letting two wave packets "go through" each other and they come out undisturbed. It's a completely boring and unremarkable experiment that is greatly undervalued by students. I didn't think of it anything myself either until I understood how in physics it's usually the absence of something that produces the "big effects" (e.g. relativity as the absence of a background).

Comment: is this right: "The entangled pair from the BBO crystal is always generated in such a way that the signal photon has the same momentum as the original photon, and the idler photon has the opposite momentum. This means that the signal photon will always hit the same spot on D0 as the original photon would have, regardless of where the pair was generated in the BBO crystal. The idler photon, by contrast, will hit different spots on D1-D4 depending on where the pair was generated. This is why the which-path information of the idler photon determines whether interference is observed or not on D0."

Comment: When Kervan tells Erdal which photons hits D1, and then Erdal looks at these photons' entangled counterparts in DX, then the pattern in this subset of DX should match with D1. But the photons hits the DX before their entangled counterparts hits D1, does it mean that when a photon hits DX, at this precise moment, the entangled counterpart already knows which path it should take ? This is just too weird to me because in order for D1 pattern matches with the corresponding susbet of D1; photons at bottom knows the future and can overcome randomness to determine which detector it goes